# Is there an Azure DevOps Pipeline condition which checks for changes to the branch since the last run

Tags: azure-devops

I want part of my build (a test deployment to cloudflare, in form context) to *only* run when the code state has changed.

Is there a simple way to do this in the Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Failing that, is there a simple way to implement a process such as this one:

1. Get latest commit hash (e.g. `git rev-parse --short HEAD`).
2. Check whether the last commit hash is stored, and if it equals the current one, quit.
3. Otherwise, proceed to store the latest commit hash and run the rest of the build step/stage.

Comment: There is, of course, a trigger for starting a build when the repo is changed and there is a `Build.Reason` that can indicate why a build is running. See [Build variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services). Assuming you have a CI trigger and a PR trigger and you allow manual runs and that the cloudflare deployment should not happen on a PR or manual build, then you would test for a build reason of `IndividualCI` or `BatchedCI`.

Comment: @Shoreline, the `latest commit hash` (git rev-parse --short HEAD) is got from source repo, which means it **has been stored**, it's also the current commit. It seems not make sense to compare them as they are one. Could you please elaborate a bit for your expectation?

Comment: I've voted to close my own question as I've been advised that the use-case I'm trying to prevent shouldn't be prevented. Thank you to everyone who has participated.